# Do the sequences defined by $a_n=a_{n-1}+(\text{the least prime factor of }a_{n-1})+1$ starting with $2,6,14,\ldots$ merge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Let $S_k$ be the sequence defined by $a_k(1)=k,\ a_k(n)=a_k(n-1)+(\text{the least prime factor of }a_k(n-1))+1$.

A diagram of these sequences for around $k<100$ is shown below. As you can see, $S_3$ merges with $S_2$ at $211$, and more unexpectedly, $S_{102}$ merges with $S_{50}$ at $64471$. On the other hand, there seem to be some sequences $S_k$ that never merge with $S_l$ for all $l<k$. The $k\leq1000$ which do not seem to merge are: 2, 6, 14, 26, 50, 62, 66, 86, 134, 170, 182, 186, 230, 242, 290, 314, 366, 386, 422, 440, 462, 506, 528, 572, 614, 630, 662, 702, 762, 794, 806, 822, 842, 870, 902, 944, 950, 962.
I've checked that each term is distinct for all $a_k(n)<10^{20}$ of these.

My question is, how can we show that $S_2$ and $S_6$, and other pairs never share a term?

```
            [2]─ 5 ┬ 11┬ 23┬ 47┬ 95┬101─203┬211─╶╶╶
                 8 ┘ 20┘ 44┘ 92┘ 98┘       │
 3 ┬ 7 ┬ 15┬ 19┬ 39┬ 43┬ 87┬ 91┬ 99┬103─207┘
 4 ┘ 12┘ 16┘ 36┘ 40┘ 84┘ 88┤ 96┘100┘
                 74─ 77┬ 85┘
                 78─ 81┤
                     82┘

[6]─ 9 ┬ 13┬ 27┬ 31┬ 63┬ 67─135─╶╶╶
     10┘ 24┘ 28┤ 60┘ 64┘
     18─ 21┬ 25┘
         22┘

[14]─ 17┬ 35┬ 41┬ 83─167─╶╶(12 terms)╶╶╶2955┬2959─╶╶╶
      32┘ 38┘ 80┘                           │
  30─ 33┬ 37┬ 75┬ 79─159─╶╶(17 terms)╶╶╶2929┘
      34┘ 72┘ 76┘

        [26]─ 29┬ 59┬119┬127─╶╶╶
              56┘116┘124┤
 42─ 45┬ 49┬ 57┬ 61─ 123┘
     46┘ 54┘ 58┤
     48─ 51┬ 55┘
         52┘

[50]─ 53┬107─╶╶╶(11 terms)╶╶╶3975┬3979─╶╶╶(17 terms)╶╶╶64465┬64471─╶╶╶
     104┘                        │                          │
     110─113─╶╶╶(20 terms)╶╶╶3961┘                          │
                       102─105┬109─219─╶╶╶(38 terms)╶╶╶64467┘
                           106┘

[62]─ 65┬ 71─143─155─161─169─183─187┬199─╶╶╶
      68┘             90─ 93┬ 97─195┘
                          94┘

           [66]─ 69┬ 73─147┬151─╶╶╶
                 70┘       │
    114─117┬121─133─141─145┘
        118┤
108─111┬115┘
    112┘

[86]─ 89─179─╶╶╶
```

edit: I changed the notation to distinguish between terms from different sequences, and I calculated the merging points for $k\leq1000,n\geq5,a_k(n)<10^{20}$:
$$\begin{alignat}{3}
&a_{42}(7)&&=a_{26}(5)&&=127\\
&a_{108}(8)&&=a_{66}(5)&&=151\\
&a_{90}(5)&&=a_{62}(10)&&=199\\
&a_{3}(12)&&=a_{2}(9)&&=211\\
&a_{240}(6)&&=a_{26}(9)&&=271\\
&a_{284}(6)&&=a_{146}(4)&&=313\\
&a_{150}(6)&&=a_{30}(9)&&=331\\
&a_{336}(9)&&=a_{186}(5)&&=391\\
&a_{210}(7)&&=a_{102}(8)&&=463\\
&a_{510}(8)&&=a_{122}(8)&&=571\\
&a_{122}(8)&&=a_{6}(13)&&=571\\
&a_{602}(5)&&=a_{302}(5)&&=631\\
&a_{302}(5)&&=a_{146}(6)&&=631\\
&a_{326}(7)&&=a_{30}(12)&&=691\\
&a_{362}(9)&&=a_{182}(6)&&=781\\
&a_{390}(5)&&=a_{386}(4)&&=799\\
&a_{426}(5)&&=a_{386}(8)&&=871\\
&a_{434}(5)&&=a_{386}(13)&&=919\\
&a_{890}(5)&&=a_{102}(10)&&=931\\
&a_{236}(5)&&=a_{102}(13)&&=967\\
&a_{942}(5)&&=a_{102}(13)&&=967\\
&a_{966}(6)&&=a_{50}(12)&&=991\\
&a_{254}(6)&&=a_{242}(9)&&=1051\\
&a_{486}(8)&&=a_{242}(9)&&=1051\\
&a_{554}(5)&&=a_{134}(8)&&=1141\\
&a_{270}(10)&&=a_{6}(16)&&=1179\\
&a_{600}(5)&&=a_{596}(5)&&=1219\\
&a_{576}(9)&&=a_{572}(8)&&=1231\\
&a_{596}(6)&&=a_{66}(11)&&=1243\\
&a_{146}(9)&&=a_{66}(14)&&=1275\\
&a_{666}(11)&&=a_{30}(16)&&=1411\\
&a_{710}(7)&&=a_{366}(8)&&=1519\\
&a_{824}(6)&&=a_{194}(10)&&=1681\\
&a_{194}(11)&&=a_{62}(20)&&=1723\\
&a_{846}(6)&&=a_{404}(9)&&=1741\\
&a_{470}(8)&&=a_{230}(11)&&=1981\\
&a_{974}(5)&&=a_{948}(8)&&=1999\\
&a_{590}(5)&&=a_{290}(7)&&=2381\\
&a_{636}(10)&&=a_{66}(20)&&=2611\\
&a_{626}(7)&&=a_{66}(22)&&=2623\\
&a_{30}(25)&&=a_{14}(20)&&=2959\\
&a_{342}(14)&&=a_{14}(21)&&=2971\\
&a_{168}(12)&&=a_{14}(21)&&=2971\\
&a_{752}(7)&&=a_{366}(12)&&=3067\\
&a_{446}(8)&&=a_{110}(11)&&=3763\\
&a_{900}(14)&&=a_{110}(17)&&=3871\\
&a_{110}(24)&&=a_{50}(16)&&=3979\\
&a_{948}(10)&&=a_{50}(17)&&=4003\\
&a_{986}(7)&&=a_{230}(24)&&=4093\\
&a_{992}(15)&&=a_{462}(19)&&=4231\\
&a_{566}(17)&&=a_{290}(11)&&=4789\\
&a_{650}(7)&&=a_{614}(18)&&=5251\\
&a_{656}(9)&&=a_{614}(19)&&=5311\\
&a_{854}(9)&&=a_{62}(26)&&=6931\\
&a_{404}(20)&&=a_{2}(24)&&=7155\\
&a_{740}(13)&&=a_{14}(35)&&=12195\\
&a_{780}(16)&&=a_{762}(17)&&=12739\\
&a_{674}(16)&&=a_{662}(13)&&=21979\\
&a_{770}(32)&&=a_{186}(27)&&=53659\\
&a_{102}(44)&&=a_{50}(35)&&=64471\\
\end{alignat}$$

Comment: How many terms do we need for $S(2)$ and $S(6)$ respectively to exceed $10^{20}$ ?

Comment: Do any of the prime sequences repeat ?

Comment: $a_{624}$ and $a_{683}$ are the first terms which exceed $10^{20}$.

Comment: $S(2)$ and $S(6)$ share no number upto $10^{50}$. The first terms exceeding $10^{50}$ are very different. It is hard to imagine that those sequences eventually merge, but I am scepctical that we can prove that.

Comment: a stupid observation is that $(a_{n}, a_{n-1}) = 1$. What about $(a_n, a_{n-2})$? If we can show how primes pop up in the series, this could be a starting point to show that $S(k)$ goes faster than $S(\ell)$ under some assumptions, or that it has different primes.. I don't know it is a starting point, but I agree it is a very hard problem. Some heuristics using the 'average' value of the least prime factor?

Comment: Idea **which may lead nowhere**: Use computer to get list of sequence-pairs that do merge.  Then look for a pattern.  Then try various hypothetical predictions about what other (currently unexplored sequence-pairs) that you would predict do merge, based on various hypotheses.  If/when you find a hypothesis that always seems to predict a merge correctly, you then try to explain why.